# which one is faster: to query with criteria in one shot or to subset a large table into a smaller table and then apply criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table (TB size, ~10 billion rows, ~100 million IDs). 
I want to run a query to get some specific IDs' counts (say, 100k IDs). List of needed IDs are in another table.

I know that I can run a join query to get the results, but it is extremely time consuming (~ 5 days processing).

I am wondering if I break the script into 2 phase (1- subset the whole table based on just the IDs, 2-apply the selection criteria on the subset table), will it make any process improvement?

Comment: 5 days???? Something is horribly wrong there. We can't possibly help you with performance with a vague description like this. We would need to see the table definition including indexes, approximate row counts and the actual query you are running.

Comment: 5 days sounds excessive, and suggests that your indexing strategy is sub-optimal.

Comment: Normally I'd ask why you didn't try it and see, but if it took 5 days... I guess that's not practical. But yes, there's nowhere near enough info here to even speculate usefully.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Is this a strictly reporting server, read only? Have you looked at resource wait stats? Indexes key here to look at. Just trying to open up other areas of discussion.